# Layovers in Italy and Ireland, are documents required?

Tags: paperwork, layovers, italy, ireland

I need to know what if any documents are mandatory when your layovers are in Italy and Ireland as a US citizen, but you won't be leaving the airport.

My husband has a flight from Morocco to the US, but has layovers in both Pisa Italy and Dublin Ireland, I booked it through kiwi.com, they are giving me lists of documents that have to be filed, but the documents want info on where he will be staying in that country but he won't so I'm confused as to whether he needs to fill them out and how since he has no destination address.

Comment: Is this a single ticket or multiple separate tickets (which Kiwi often does). ?

Comment: For Pisa Airport, which has no transit area, the location will be the airport. For Dublin, you will have to go through US Preclearance at the airport. I would write 'Airport' adding the departure flight number with date and time for both cases.

Comment: Which airlines are you flying?

Answer (score 7):

The routing suggests that the first two flights are on Ryanair.

So what you have is not a flight from Morocco to the US with two layovers, what you have is three different flights.

And for each different flight, you will need to meet the visa and health entry requirements for the destination country, or you will not be allowed to board in the first place. So you will need to make sure you have all the documents in order to enter Italy, as well as to enter Ireland. You will have to do some research yourself here. Do not assume that the information that Kiwi gave you is complete.

You will also have to retrieve your luggage and drop it off again on each leg. And you may also have to go through another document check in Pisa.

I hope nothing goes wrong. If you miss the flight out of Dublin because Ryanair moved or cancelled one of the previous flights you may end up having to buy an expensive transatlantic ticket on the spot. This attempt to save some money could end up quite expensive.

Comment: The OP could try entering the itinerary details into IATA https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ and Timatic https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true

Comment: Yes. but he should treat it as three itineraries, not one.